# using regex to return new filename

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to get a filename and have it return a string.

try to turn:

plate-71-winter-hawk-final.jpg

into:

winter hawk final

where plate might also be uppercase. Here is what I have so far, doesn't seem to work

```
var theRegEx = new RegExp('[Plate|plate]-\d+-(.*).jpg');
var theString = "plate-71-winter-hawk-final.jpg"

var newString = theString.replace(theRegEx, theString);

newString;
```

Comment: Why do you need a regex to do this? You can use a combination of Substring and Replace to do this much quicker than you could have written this post.

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware. Thought regex might be easiest way?

Comment: Regex is much more complex than simple string manipulation, particularly when you're dealing with this type of operation. You don't need that complexity here.

Comment: **Rule #1 to use RegEx:** _Look for alternatives of using RegEx._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the *"Rule #1"* doesn't offer a better way:

```
var newString = theString.replace(/^[Pp]late-\d+-(.*)\.jpg$/, '$1')
                         .replace(/-/g, ' ');
```

Take care when you use a string with the object syntax to escape backslahes:

```
var theRegEx = new RegExp('^[Pp]late-\\d+-(.*)\\.jpg$');
```

Note that a character class is only a set of characters, you can't use it to put substrings and special regex characters loose their meaning inside it. `[Plate|plate]` is the same thing than `[Pplate|]`

You can write it like this too (without string):

```
var theRegEx = new RegExp(/^[Pp]late-\d+-(.*)\.jpg$/);
```

Comment: This returns `winter-hawk-final`. Shouldn't `-` be removed ?

Comment: Yes, it need to be replaced with a space.

Comment: yeah  .replace(/-/g, ' '); seems to fix this, its in his example. this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following script. It's not dependent on length of string as long as it follows standard pattern:

```
var data = "plate-71-winter-hawk-final.jpg";
var rx = /(?:plate\-\d+\-)(.*)(?=\.)/i;

var match = rx.exec(data);
if(match != null){
   data = match[1];
   data = data.replace(/\-/g, ' ');
}

console.log(data);
```

It will print:

winter hawk final